# How can I access OpenStreetMap API data using PHP?

Tags: php, api, openstreetmap

I am trying to access OpenStreetMap data using PHP, but I cannot find any clear answers on how to do so. The URL I am trying to pull data from works when I search it in the browser.
Here is the URL I am trying: `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=jacksonville,florida&format=json`

And this is how I am trying to access it in my PHP file, but it always returns nothing.

```
    $search_url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=jacksonville,florida&format=json";
    $json = file_get_contents($search_url);

    print_r($json);
    echo "json=" . $json;
    $decoded = json_decode($json, true);
    $lat = $decoded[0]["lat"];
    $lng = $decoded[0]["lon"];
    echo " latitude=".$lat . " -----" . "longitude=".$lng;
```

How can I fix this? My end goal is to simply get the latitude and longitude of a city, state.

Comment: hello, I want to show an open street map using lat, long. what can I do for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that the api is refusing to serve a request without a valid User-Agent and http referrer header, try setting this and it should work, for example:

```
<?php

$search_url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=jacksonville,florida&format=json";

$httpOptions = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "User-Agent: Nominatim-Test"
    ]
];

$streamContext = stream_context_create($httpOptions);
$json = file_get_contents($search_url, false, $streamContext);

print_r($json);
echo "json=" . $json;
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$lat = $decoded[0]["lat"];
$lng = $decoded[0]["lon"];
echo " latitude=".$lat . " -----" . "longitude=".$lng;
```

Comment: That worked perfect! Thank you so much, I saw other people said similar things, but I am new to PHP, and I couldn't get it to work on my own.

Comment: So how did you know to make the line "header" => "User-Agent: Nominatim-Test"? what does that do?

Comment: It's not that obvious either, if I don't set the header, I get a 403 Forbidden error. But with the header it works.

Comment: The User-Agent header tells the webservice the client type. A lot of APIs will refuse to serve without this header set so it's good practice to set it to something reasonable when making API calls. You could probably set it to almost anything as long as it is not empty!

Comment: good to know. Well thank you for your help, I spent hours searching for a correct answer haha

Comment: The server actually tells you what's wrong. "*You should in particular verify that you have set a custom HTTP referrer or HTTP user agent that identifies your application*" `file_get_contents` just doesn't return anything on unsuccessful request, unlike curl.

Comment: Thanks very much, @gre_gor!

Comment: hello, I want to show an open street map using lat, long. what can I do for that?